# What is the equivalent of bokeh's push_notebook in holoviews?

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I can refresh a bokeh picture after updating ColumnDataSource, like this:

```
t = show(p, notebook_handle=True)
##### new notebook cell #####
src.data['foo'][0] = 'bar'
push_notebook(handle=t)
```

but, how can I refresh a holoviews picture using python?

Comment: Do the examples at http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Streaming_Data.html help?

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar Thank you for your comment! I think I should read the doc from beginning.